# React routing. How to generate address

Tags: reactjs, react-router

guys! Need help.

I am generating links to categories of FAQ module. Got a problem. Here is my code and error report is above this.

```
        <ul>
    {
      this.props.categories.map((category) => {
        return (
          <li className="text-white d-inline-block w-100 clearfix ml-0" key={ category.id }>{ category.name }
             <a className="btn btn-primary float-right" onClick={ () => {
               this.handleEditOpenModal(category.id);
             } }>Edit</a>
             <NavLink to={'/' + category.id } className="btn btn-warning float-right">Add To</NavLink>
             <a className="btn btn-danger float-right"> Delete </a>
           </li>
        );
      })
    }
    </ul>
```

This code gives me these mistakes

```
> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in h1 (created by QuestionsAndAnswers)
    in div (created by QuestionsAndAnswers)
    in div (created by QuestionsAndAnswers)
    in QuestionsAndAnswers (created by Connect(QuestionsAndAnswers))
    in Connect(QuestionsAndAnswers) (created by DashBoardPage)
    in div (created by DashBoardPage)
    in div (created by DashBoardPage)
    in div (created by DashBoardPage)
    in div (created by DashBoardPage)
    in DashBoardPage (created by Route)
    in Route (created by AppRouter)
    in Switch (created by AppRouter)
    in div (created by AppRouter)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by AppRouter)
    in AppRouter
    in Provider
    at invariant (invariant.js?7313:42)
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js?cada:8591)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js?cada:9503)
    at reconcileChildrenAtPriority (react-dom.development.js?cada:10127)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js?cada:10118)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js?cada:10370)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:10609)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:12573)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js?cada:12682)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?cada:1299)
> 
> The above error occurred in the <h1> component:
    in h1 (created by QuestionsAndAnswers)
    in div (created by QuestionsAndAnswers)
    in div (created by QuestionsAndAnswers)
    in QuestionsAndAnswers (created by Connect(QuestionsAndAnswers))
    in Connect(QuestionsAndAnswers) (created by DashBoardPage)
    in div (created by DashBoardPage)
    in div (created by DashBoardPage)
    in div (created by DashBoardPage)
    in div (created by DashBoardPage)
    in DashBoardPage (created by Route)
    in Route (created by AppRouter)
    in Switch (created by AppRouter)
    in div (created by AppRouter)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by AppRouter)
    in AppRouter
    in Provider

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

> react-dom.development.js?cada:1345 Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See react-crossorigin-error for more information.
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?cada:1345)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?cada:1195)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:12800)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js?cada:13244)
    at performFiberBatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js?cada:1646)
    at stackBatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js?cada:1637)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js?cada:1651)
    at Object.batchedUpdatesWithControlledComponents [as batchedUpdates] (react-dom.development.js?cada:1664)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js?cada:1874)
```

As I can understand the problem is near to line

```
                 <NavLink to={'/' + category.id } className="btn btn-warning float-right">Add To</NavLink>
```

If I do not generate address ( e.g. `<NavLink to="/5ecf1cc7-e343-4ce9-bf71-26e02efeb7ba">...`) In this case I have no problem, but it is not what I need.

What do you think? Thanx

Comment: somewhere you are trying to render a object

Comment: How can I convert it? If I use category.id.toString() I have the same mistake. If use JSON.stringify(category.id) - no mistake but adress is like this http://localhost:8080/"242fd964b-9ff6-408c-b7a3-b40a51efdcb6"

Comment: console.log(typeof category.id); Says: String

Comment: this error will not come up if you are setting props with an object. this occurs only when  your react component is trying to render a direct object..

Comment: where is the h1 created by QuestionsAndAnswers?